# Como fazer CSS de uma div com inclinação de ambos os lados? Conforme imagem:

Tags: css

Gostaria de fazer esse efeito para divisão de seção, algum direcionamento?[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: certo, já tentou algum coisa?

Comment: Você precisa sempre postar um código do que já tentou, onde está errando. Se está começando do zero, e não tem nem um início, sugiro procurar ajuda em blogs, Medium e vídeos aulas. Assim, ao tentar e ter algum problema, procure o Stack para ajudar em um ponto objetivo.